# how to install struts2 in netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans, struts2, netbeans-8

I need to install struts2 since netbeans new version 8.* comes only with the old version of struts 1.3.*. I have searched all over on the net but i could not find any proper answer for this. Somewhere they have suggested to download the plugin nbstruts2support-nb6.9.1 which i have downloaded from http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39218

In its zip there were three plugins for struts2 so i have installed 2 of them successfully but when I tried to install the third plugin file which is struts2 Support it gave me this error and could'nt install.

> Some plugins require plugin Editor Library to be installed.
>   The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.10.1.10.2 (release version 2) but only 3.49.2.22.43 (of release version different from 2) was found.  The following plugin is affected:       Struts2 Support

Comment: You don't need a plugin to develop a S2 based application. Have you considered using some other ide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about plugin, it's not so much useful as in Struts 1.x, and there's no any plugin that is able to provide *full* support for Struts2. However, Struts2 has it's own plugins' arsenal. And each of them works differently that you have to learn the docs and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roman C, however i have setup everything manually in netbeans without any plugin. My intention is to run the application in netbeans but now i am unable to run my action which gives me error 404 through glass fish. Please if you have time take a look at my other posted question on stackover flow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911439/struts2-confgured-in-netbeans-8-returning-http-status-404-not-found

Comment: Upvoted your questions, recommend you do the same, however your question is too difficult to answer, I have tried similar questions on SO without success ;)