# Struts2 confgured in netbeans 8 returning HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: jsp, netbeans, struts2, netbeans-8, build-dependencies

I have tried everything to run my first Struts2 demo application but i am failed to run it. I have followed the tutorial on

http://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/struts2/struts-2-netbeans-tutorial.html

Here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

      <display-name>Struts2 Demo App</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="Struts2Demo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="controller.HelloWorld">
            <result>/message.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <!-- Add your actions here -->
    </package>
</struts>
```

here is controller file

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import model.Message;

public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {
    private Message message;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        setMessage(new Message()); // get data from model
        return SUCCESS;
    }



      public Message getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

    }
```

Here is my jsp file

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="Struts2Demo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="controller.HelloWorld">
            <result>/message.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <!-- Add your actions here -->
    </package>
</struts>
```

and here is the model file

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package model;

public class Message {
    private String message = "Hello World!";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

My file structure is

[image]

> Netbeans version: 8.1 
>   Glassfish server: 4   All struts2 configuration are setup manually
>   without any plugin

Comment: What other URLs did you try? Did you try JDK 7?

Comment: I have tried http://localhost:8080/Struts2Demo/HelloWorld , http://localhost:8080/Struts2Demo/HelloWorld.action , http://localhost:8080/Struts2Demo/

Comment: It so very small subset of urls and a huge one missed by you.

Comment: I will appreciate if you can guide me , this is first project i am trying to run on netbeans i do not have experience in struts2 and all the examples i have tried gives me same error. I am using JDK 7

Comment: First you need to build the deployment artifact or `.war` file to deploy on the server, then you need to check if it has deployed at the specified context `/Struts2Demo`. Put `index.html` file to the root and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried with index.html file it works fine, but only when i call the controller action then it gives me 404 error. Here is my war file , https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104183650/Struts2Demo.war . I am using builtin glassfish server of netbeans ,

Comment: Then check the server log file to see if errors and exceptions are thrown, post them to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your startup logs indicate precisely what the problem is, although you'll run into more of the same, since you're not deploying all the required dependencies.

At a minimum, for your app, you need:

```
WEB-INF/lib
├── commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
├── commons-io-2.2.jar
├── commons-lang3-3.2.jar
├── commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
├── freemarker-2.3.22.jar
├── javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
├── ognl-3.0.6.jar
├── struts2-core-2.3.24.1.jar
└── xwork-core-2.3.24.1.jar
```

This is why you should be using Maven, Gradle, or an equivalent dependency manager. Each library used by a Java application has its *own* dependencies, and you are missing a lot of them.

I used http://mvnrepository.com/ to manually grab the libraries your app requires, using startup error messages as a guide. This is a skill you should acquire even though it's managed for you by Maven/etc. Without knowing what all it handles you'll be tempted to think you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you dave , i have just manually included these libs and changed little bit structure and now everything looks fine. Once again thanks for your help

Comment: Why did you add a fileupload interceptor? OP doesn't upload anything. Manually adding libraries contradicts to your suggestion to use dependency manager.

Comment: @RomanC There's nothing anywhere in the answer about interceptors, and upload is a dependency, if you check out the mvnrepository page. His project was a war file with no pom file, and I wasn't going to recreate OP's build environment. The process of finding and understanding transitive dependencies is a skill one should have, and without knowing the pain of doing it manually, the appreciation of the tools is lessened. There's zero contradiction-if you don't know what the tools do, or why, you can't even start to troubleshoot.

Comment: OP is not doing any uploading/downloading functionality and  adding excessive dependency would be considered as the server overhead. Nor it's not used by the maven configuration that is absent. A lot of other requirements that are normally downloaded from the Maven repository where OP should download/or mirrors that are officially recognized. To suggest the resource that has particular relationship to the original is a big obstacle which leads to misplacing original libraries with fake ones that usually  produce invisible bugs and compromise the security system.